# Graph theoretic name for minimal subgraph that connects to full graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with vertices $V$ and edge set $E$. Define $T$ to be the minimal subgraph of $G$ (in terms of number of vertices), such that every vertex $v\in V\backslash T$ connects to at least one vertex of $T$, via an edge $e\in E$. For example, if $G=K_n$ is a complete graph, then $T$ can be a single vertex, since it connects to every other vertex. Or if $G$ is a square graph on 4 vertices, $T$ can be the two vertices diagonally opposite of each other.

Is there a common name for $T$ in graph-theory literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $T\subseteq V(G)$ with the property, that every vertex $v\in V\setminus T$ is adjacent to at least one vertex in $T,$ is called a [*dominating set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set). A dominating set of minimum cardinality is called a [*minimum dominating set*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimumDominatingSet.html). The minimum number of vertices in a dominating set is called the *domination number* of the graph, in symbols $\gamma(G).$

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexR. You're welcome. I changed my answer slightly; the term "minimum dominating set" seems to be reasonably standard.